# function still executing even with setTimeout and promises

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

I am attempting to use promises to wait until the data has been filled in before triggering the 20 second `setTimeout` but the `setTimeout` is not halting the function from executing.

Any suggestions for forcing `finishedGame()` to wait 20 seconds?

```
var q1 = "SELECT name, pic, link FROM users where id = " + winner;
connection.query(q1, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var pic = results[0].pic;
        var name = results[0].name;
        var link = results[0].link ;
        var winnerInfo = {
            id: winner,
            name: name,
            total: total,
            totalItems: totalitems,
            pic: pic,
            link: link,
            percentage: playerPercentage
        }
            io.sockets.emit('animation', { 
            winnerData : winnerInfo 
        }); 
        resolve(winnerInfo);
    }).then(function(winnerInfo){
        setTimeout(finishedGame(winner, winnerInfo), 20000);
    });
    connection.end();
});
```

Comment: You need to return a promise for the timeout from the `then` callback, otherwise the chain won't wait.

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a callback function, not a call.

Comment: `if (err) throw err;` is probably the most common wrong code I see here.  That just throws into an async handler which does nothing useful and nothing you can catch.  Put the error inside your promise and do a reject if there's an error.

Comment: That code comes from the readme of node-mysql. What exactly should it be then?

Comment: You can have to process the error in the `if` statement or call some callback to communicate the error to a higher level.  throwing from an async callback does not do anything useful or catchable.

Answer (score 2):

To correctly delay the execution of `finishedGame()` you should wrap the function call, not call the function. Try this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
 finishedGame(winner, winnerInfo)
}, 20000);
```

---

- `setTimeout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout